# How to update nix language version (builtins.langVersion)?

Tags: nix, nixos

I want to run nixpkgs test locally, I have found [this manual](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/doc/manual/development/running-nixos-tests.xml), but it doesn't work

```
$ cd my/nixpkgs
$ nix-build --show-trace nixos/tests/login.nix
error: while evaluating the attribute ‘buildCommand’ of the derivation ‘vm-test-run-login’ at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:148:11:
while evaluating the attribute ‘buildCommand’ of the derivation ‘nixos-test-driver-login’ at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:148:11:
while evaluating the attribute ‘buildCommand’ of the derivation ‘nixos-vm’ at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:148:11:
while evaluating the attribute ‘text’ of the derivation ‘run-nixos-vm’ at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:148:11:
while evaluating anonymous function at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/closure-info.nix:9:1, called from /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/nixos/modules/virtualisation/qemu-vm.nix:105:13:
assertion failed at /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/closure-info.nix:11:1
```

because of this assert

```
assert builtins.langVersion >= 5;
```

How to update langVersion?

```
$ nix-repl
Welcome to Nix version 1.11.16. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> builtins.langVersion
3

nix-repl>
```

Comment: Presumably you have to update the Nix software itself, since the version of the language recognized is determined by the code in the Nix software.  I'm not sure how to do that but you can probably search for "update nix" or "install latest version of nix" or something.  The answer might depend on whether you are using NixOS.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I did, I have updated to unstable `nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable nixpkgs && sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` and it didnt work

Comment: Finnaly found what I did wrong, I had to use `sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable nixos`

Comment: All is fine, except volume is not working

Comment: I have found another way of running test without upgrading system: `nix-shell -p nixUnstable --run "nix-instantiate --eval -E 'builtins.langVersion'"` returns `5`

Comment: or `export NIX_PATH="nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-18.03.tar.gz" && nix-shell -p nix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay on 17.09 for a while longer, you can upgrade just Nix using this NixOS configuration:

```
{ pkgs, ... }: {
  nix.package = pkgs.nixUnstable;
}
```

Otherwise you may prefer to switch to 18.03 instead of unstable. If you're going to use unstable, make sure you're using *nixos*-unstable, not *nixpkgs*-unstable. See https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nixpkgs#Channels

Comment: `If you're going to use unstable, make sure you're using nixos-unstable, not nixpkgs-unstable` yes, that actually was second error: the first one is that I should use sudo, the second is that I should use nixos-unstable instead of nixpkgs-unstable

Answer (score 0):

Thx to David Grayson

I had to update nixos to unstable (`sudo nix-channel` is important)

```
sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable nixos
sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade
nix-instantiate --eval -E '(import <nixos> {}).lib.nixpkgsVersion'
nix-instantiate --eval -E 'builtins.langVersion'
```